# How to remove padding from community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have created below LWC page

HTML:

```
<template>
    <p>Hello From the community page.</p>
</template>
```

no CSS and JS added just above 3 lines in the HTML

Added it on the community as shown below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and now previewing this page it automatically added top and left padding, which is not at all required.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

how can I remove the padding/margin and align the static text at the top of the page.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDPp6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG1Vg.png

Answer (score 0):

The LWC will inherit some styles from the template being used. These styles can be overridden. The instructions for the same are at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm